# AWS CLI create batch job

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a bash script that creates a manifest.csv file example below, and then I use that to create an S3 batch job, I ran it using the console and it works so roles and permissions are correct, any help will be appreciated.

```
test-bucket-batch,Test/testing1.json \
test-bucket-batch,Test/testing2.json \
test-bucket-batch,Test/testing3.json \
test-bucket-batch,Test/testing4.json 

aws s3control create-job \
    --account-id $ACCOUNT_ID \
    --region $REGION \
    --confirmation-required \
    --client-request-token $(uuidgen) \
    --operation '{"S3PutObjectCopy":{"TargetResource":"arn:aws:s3:::'$BUCKET_NAME'/object_restore/"}}' \
    --manifest '{"Spec":{"Format":"S3BatchOperations_CSV_20180820","Fields":["Bucket","Key"]},"Location":{"ObjectArn":"arn:aws:s3:::'$BUCKET_NAME'/object_restore/manifest.csv","ETag":'$ETAG'}}' \
    --report '{"Bucket":"arn:aws:s3:::'$BUCKET_NAME'/object_restore/","Prefix":"final-reports", "Format":"Report_CSV_20180820","Enabled": true,"ReportScope":"AllTasks"}' \
    --description 'S3 Copy Job' \
    --priority 42 \
    --role-arn $ROLE_ARN
```

```
ERROR: An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the CreateJob operation: Request invalid
```

Comment: Well, the command looks good, but I wonder if there is a quote somewhere I'm not seeing causing an issue. Are you sure all the variables used are available in the environment in which the command is run?

Comment: Hi i have tried running it via shell as well with the variable values entered manually, same error

Answer (score 2):

The issue was related to the prefix

```
aws s3control create-job \
--account-id $ACCOUNT_ID \
--region $REGION \
--confirmation-required \
--client-request-token $(uuidgen) \
--operation '{"S3PutObjectCopy":{"TargetResource":"arn:aws:s3:::'$BUCKET_NAME'","TargetKeyPrefix":"/object_restore/"}}' \
--manifest '{"Spec":{"Format":"S3BatchOperations_CSV_20180820","Fields":["Bucket","Key"]},"Location":{"ObjectArn":"arn:aws:s3:::'$BUCKET_NAME'/object_restore/manifest.csv","ETag":'$ETAG'}}' \
--report '{"Bucket":"arn:aws:s3:::'$BUCKET_NAME'","Prefix":"/object_restore/final-reports", "Format":"Report_CSV_20180820","Enabled": true,"ReportScope":"AllTasks"}' \
--description 'S3 Copy Job' \
--priority 42 \
--role-arn $ROLE_ARN
```

Note the fields changed where:

1. `operation` where `TargetKeyPrefix` was added: `"TargetKeyPrefix":"/object_restore/"`
2. `report` where `Prefix` was changed to:
   `"Prefix":"/object_restore/final-reports"`